# I have a MySQL table in which I want to create 67 columns. Is there any way I can do it? I am using XAMPP as a server

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL table in which I want to create 67 columns. But whenever I am creating the table and click save it gives an error. Now I understand this is a MySQL limitation. Is there any way I can do it? I am using XAMPP as a server.

Comment: can you please elaborate?  what is the error?  what is the create statement?

Comment: Please see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3972/error-code-1117-too-many-columns-mysql-column-limit-on-table

Comment: Particularly note conclusion of first answer in ^. Its probably in need of better normalization.

Comment: Actually, I was creating the table with the help of the GUI of phpmyadmin. The error says Just  "undefined". But in case of other tables I have in my database there is no error. Though they are not as big as this one I am facing problem with.